# Unable to display values from a nested formGroup inside a formArray in a reactive form. Getting following error : Cannot find control with path

Tags: angular, nested, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

I am unable to get the values from a formArray consisting of dynamically added formGroups. I am able to save the values but when i am trying to pre populate the form in order to create  edit form page, i so not see any data from the FormArray.

```
   <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="3" [rowspan]="6">
  <div formArrayName="itemGroupMappings" class="ScrollStyle">

    <button mat-raised-button color="primary"  type="button" (click)="onAddButtonClick()" >Add group and OEM nos.</button>
    
   
   
<div *ngFor="let itemGroupMappingControl of getItemGroupDetailControls(); let i = index" [formGroupName] = "i"  >

   
    <mat-form-field>
            
       <div formGroupName="itemGroup">
             
            <mat-label>Group Name</mat-label>
            <input matInput type ="text" placeholder="" name="groupName" autocomplete="off" 
                    formControlName="groupName" class="form-control" >
       
     </div>
    
    </mat-form-field>
     <mat-form-field>
      <div>
            <mat-label >Oem Nos.</mat-label>
            <input  matInput type ="text" placeholder="" name="oemNo" autocomplete="off" 
                                        formControlName="oemNo" class="form-control" >
     </div>
     </mat-form-field>
   

     <button mat-raised-button color="warn"  type="button" (click)="onDeleteClick(i)" >Delete Group</button>

    </div>
     
     
 </div>

  
</mat-grid-tile>
```

```
this.editDeleteForm = this.formBuilder.group({

      'itemCode' : new FormControl(),
      'itemName' : new FormControl(),
      'itemGroupMappings' : this.formBuilder.array([this.addItemGroup()])
   
     
   

  });
}

  addItemGroup() : FormGroup
  {
    return this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        'itemGroup' : new FormGroup({
          'groupName' : new FormControl('')
        }),
        'oemNo' : new FormControl('')
      }
    )
  
  }


 





  editItem(item : Item)
  {
    this.editDeleteForm.patchValue({

      itemCode : item.itemCode,
      itemName  : item.itemName,

    });

       this.editDeleteForm.setControl('itemGroupMappings',this.setExistingGroupMappings(this.itemById.itemGroupMappings));
   
    }

    

   
  


  setExistingGroupMappings(mappings : ItemGroupDetail[]) : FormArray
  {
    const formArray = new FormArray([]);

    mappings.forEach( s => {
     formArray.push( this.formBuilder.group({
        itemGroup :  ({
          groupName : s.itemGroup.groupName

        }),
        oemNo : s.oemNo

             }

           )
        );
    });

    return formArray;

  }

 

  getItemGroupDetailControls()
  {  
    console.log(((<FormArray>this.editDeleteForm.get('itemGroupMappings')).controls));
    return (<FormArray>this.editDeleteForm.get('itemGroupMappings')).controls;

  
  }
```

My model.ts file looks like this

```
import { ItemType } from "./item-type.model";


export interface Item{
    itemCode : String,
    itemName : String,
    oemNos : String,
 
    
    itemGroupMappings : ItemGroupDetail[],
    

} 

export interface ItemGroupDetail{
   
    itemGroup :  ItemGroup,
    oemNo :  String
}

export interface ItemGroup{
  
  groupName : String
}
```

Values are perfectly getting saved in itemGroupMappings, see my json below which i have copied from console :

```
itemGroupMappings: Array(2)
0:
itemGroup: {groupId: "G01", groupName: "JCB"}
itemGroupDetailId: {itemCode: "DUMMY09", groupName: "JCB"}
oemNo: "87089900"
__proto__: Object
1:
itemGroup: {groupId: "G03", groupName: "MASSEY"}
itemGroupDetailId: {itemCode: "DUMMY09", groupName: "MASSEY"}
oemNo: "90199191"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
itemName: "DUMMY09"
```

However i am getting following error :

core.js:5980 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'itemGroupMappings -> 0 -> itemGroup -> groupName'

```
edit-delete-item.component.ts:175 (2) [FormGroup, FormGroup]
core.js:5980 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'itemGroupMappings -> 1 -> itemGroup -> groupName'
    at _throwError (forms.js:2574)
    at setUpControl (forms.js:2392)
    at FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:5626)
    at FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:6177)
    at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:6122)
    at FormControlName.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (core.js:1471)
    at callHook (core.js:2490)
```

I am unable to understand how to correctly get the data from itemGroupMappings FormArray in the edit page.
Please help, as i am new to angular and am stuck with this for a very long time now. Referred various posts but am unable to correct it.
I am able to display 'oemNo' correctly on the html page, when i do so by commenting out

```
 <div formGroupName="itemGroup">
             
            <mat-label>Group Name</mat-label>
            <input matInput type ="text" placeholder="" name="groupName" autocomplete="off" 
                    formControlName="groupName" class="form-control" >
       
     </div>
```

however while accessing groupName, i get above error. Please adivise.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.value` instead of `.controls`. Even though it seems like what you have done should work, it wont. Because FormArray stores the values in `.value`. Something like this:

```
getItemGroupDetailControls()
  {
// Don't do this  
   
console.log(((<FormArray>this.editDeleteForm.get('itemGroupMappings')).controls));
    return (<FormArray>this.editDeleteForm.get('itemGroupMappings')).controls;
  
  
// Do this instead

console.log(((<FormArray>this.editDeleteForm.get('itemGroupMappings')).value));
    return (<FormArray>this.editDeleteForm.get('itemGroupMappings')).value;

  }
```

Because at the end of the day, `itemGroupMappings` is still a formControl first and formArray later.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but i am still getting the same error. Value doesnt make any difference. In my code the i think the issue is because there is another formGroup inside a formGroup. If there would have been just a formGroup and inside it formControls then we could have easily fetched it but due to nested formGroup, i am unable to get the formArray values. I might not be correct, but i had this observation of nested formGroups.